# can you show an icon in an xpages iNotes calendar control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have been trying to get an icon to show in the iNotes calendar control. I set the colEntryIcon to the programatic name of the column in the view. Still no luck. Also I noticed when dissecting the Teamroom template, the Calendar page in that app does not show an icon even though the colEntryIcon is set and it does show an icon in the classic notes view in teamroom. Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Add a code sample of what you tried. Also use Firebug to see if the browser actually tries

Answer (score 2):

I just gave it a try with the teamroom template:

If I choose one of the "bigger" grids like 2 weeks, or month, icons only show onMouseOver:
[image: iNotes calendar, month view]

If I choose a different calendarType with a smaller grid (week, day, or below, or summarized view) icons show both onMouseOver and in the grid:
[image: iNotes calendar, week view]

Please double-check that the REST service's colEntryIcon property holds the correct programmatic name for your icon column (for a standard mail calendar that would be "$149")!

Comment: Lothar, Switching views like you mentioned does show that icon as in your images. Is there anyway to have it show the smae icon as it would show in the notes client view? For example, the teamroom meeting in the notes client shows the handshake icon. Many thanks

Comment: I don't know; I guess it should show any icon that's shown in the referenced icon column as long as that specific icon exists on the server (\dominoData\domino\icons\). But that's just an assumption, haven't tested it (yet)